# How to place sticky footer div's next to each other when bottom:0 is set dynamically

Tags: css, html, css-position, sticky-footer, sticky

I am trying to place divs next to each other of which the divs act like a sticky-footer using position:absolute and bottom:0

HTML: (`note that I could have many of these with different id but the same class`)

```
<div id="s6234" class="sticky">
    <div id="s_content">
    Hello
    </div>
</div>


<div id="s7243" class="sticky">
    <div id="s_content">
    Hello
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sticky{position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0;width:200px;height:100px;background-color:#aaa}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZqaDe/

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/ZqaDe/show

**EDIT:**
I don't know how many divs there are every time. The divs there are appended dynamically. In the actual app, those div's can be deleted, moved or added so it they will keep changing every time. So basically I want a way so that the are placed every time next to each other.

**EDIT 2:**
I don't think I am able to wrap all div's inside a main sticky footer and set a float:left so that they are placed next to each other. In the real example, **the position:absolute and bottoom:0 is set dynamically**. *Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u2nda/*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have an empty footer div in which you append the divs you are minimizing. You then just need to set the position to relative, float the div left and reset top and left to 0.

So your JQuery string would become:

```
$(this).parent().parent().appendTo("#footer")
                         .css('position','relative')
                         .css('float','left')
                         .css('height','45')
                         .css('top','0')
                         .css('left','0')
                         .find('#s_content').hide();
```

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u2nda/2/**

#### Edit

Or better still, change the `position` to `static`, that way you do not need to reset the `top` and `left` values:

```
$(this).parent().parent().appendTo("#footer")
                         .css('position','static')
                         .css('float','left')
                         .css('height','45')
                         .find('#s_content').hide();
```

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u2nda/3/**

#### Edit 2

Or even better, just append classes that do not overwrite your inline CSS:

```
.tabMe {
    float: left;
    height: 45px;
    position: static;
}

.tabMe #s_head{
    border: 0;
}

.tabMe #s_content{
    display: none;
}
```

And your JQuery to show / hide could become:

```
$('#s_head button').on('click', function(){
    var check = $(this).parent().parent();
    if( !check.hasClass("tabMe"))
        check.appendTo("#footer").addClass("tabMe")
    else
        check.appendTo("body").removeClass("tabMe")                         
});
```

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u2nda/4/**

Answer (score 0):

You just need to move the second `div` to the right: `#s7243 { left: 200px; }`. If you had a third `div`, you'd need to move it over even more: `#third-one { left: 400px; }`.

Comment: Sorry I should note that I don't know how many divs there are every time. The divs there are appended so. In the actual app, those div's can be deleted, or added it keeps changing every time.

Comment: Then I would just place one big container `div` down there so I wouldn't have to worry about positioning so many other `div`s. [I made a fiddle for this](http://jsfiddle.net/2zTbX/).

Answer (score 0):

I would place the divs in a main container that had my position absolute and then float your blocks.

Example http://jsfiddle.net/ZqaDe/3/

Comment: I thought of that but what if you set the sticky footer dynamically: http://jsfiddle.net/u2nda/

Answer (score 0):

I think that best option would be to wrap your "sticky" divs. See [my demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KX36x/)

```
<div class="sticky">
 <div id="s6234" class="left">
    <div id="s_content">
    Hello
    </div>
 </div>


 <div id="s7243" class="left">
    <div id="s_content">
    Hello
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sticky{position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0;width:200px;height:100px;background-color:#aaa}
.left{float: left;margin-left: 10px;background: yellow;}
```

Comment: I thought of that but what if you set the sticky footer dynamically: http://jsfiddle.net/u2nda/

Comment: simple fix would be just to insert html into wrapper, instead of setting bottom:0 you could take innerhtml of the div and append it to my wrapper. By the way: you have two divs with id s_head and s_content :) i doubt however that it is the best and efficient solution. A better one seems to set not only bottom: 0, but also left: X, where X is the sum of the width of all minimized divs (for example you can add class "minimized" or something like this and easily count their width). Be aware that if you have A LOT of such divs, then you must check browser's width as well

Comment: This was the way I was going to do it but I thought there could a better way of which I may not be aware of. Isn't there a way to say take $(this) and set it inside a div of which that div will be placed in the footer. Same as your example but on button click, take it from position absolute and throw it inside the .sticky div.

Comment: as I have already written I am only aware of copying the object but I guess it would be a good idea to ask separate question exactly about this issue